# Unable to access WebStorm internal server using IP address

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I installed WebStorm on my PC and started NodeJS server. I am able to access it from Chrome and Firefox browsers using `localhost` but not with my PC's IP address.

I followed instructions given [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206340369-How-do-I-access-the-html-by-ip-address-). I verified whether extension is enabled or not in Chrome as well checked the port no in WebStorm's `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger`. My PC's firewall has been turned off. Still I am unable to access it using IP address.

Can anyone guide me how to go about this?

I am running WebStorm in my PC and trying to access it from the same machine through above browsers.

Using WebStorm 2016.3.3 version.

Comment: can it be related to your host file settings?

Comment: But i am able to access the applications using ip address when i run other webservers external to webstorm.

Comment: Can you post your code snippet? Try let your app listening on `0.0.0.0` address.

Comment: It is webstorm's internal webserver which i am unable to access using ip address in which i created angularJS project and trying to access it. How to configure 0.0.0.0 in webstorm's angular project.

Comment: @SatyaNarayana Please change that port number from default to another one. Default port will work on `localhost` only -- even if you have enabled "Can accept external connection". That's a security measure ... as this port is used for other stuff as well (and not just built-in web server -- communication with Chrome extension/Live Edit etc).

Answer (score 3):

Here are my findings when connecting to WebStorm's internal web server via Chrome using the following:

- WebStorm 2018.1 Build #WS-181.4203.535
- Windows 7 6.1, 64 Bit Pro
- Chrome Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Chrome connected to `localhost:63342` but returned *connection refused* when attempting to connect to WebStorm at `<ip address of machine>:63342`, even with Windows Firewall disabled.

I first configured WebStorm to listen at port 63343 instead of 63342 and still had the same result.  Unexpectedly, with this setting **WebStorm answered at both localhost:63342 and localhost:63343**, even after restarting WebStorm.

I then noticed that with either of these ports, WebStorm's *Can accept external connections* checkbox was grayed out and unchecked.  Changing WebStorm's port to 1338 alone still resulted in *Connection refused* at `http://<ip address of machine>:1338`.  Turning off Windows firewall did not affect this.

Since WebStorm's *Can accept external connections* checkbox became usable after I changed its port to 1338, I now checked the box.  Chrome was now able to reach WebStorm at `http://<ip address of machine>:1338`.

So it seems that **it is not the port itself that makes a difference, but WebStorm's *Can accept external connections* checkbox**. Note that checking this box may be a security risk if you are using a shared network since WebStorm will now serve pages to other stations as well as your own.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer for this in [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207042105-Getting-connection-refused-on-built-in-web-server) post I changed the default port no to something else and now i am able to access the page from the browser using ip address.